# A projectile motion problem with solution to be verified.

Tags: derivatives

In a projectile motion problem, the height of the object from the ground is given by $y=ut-1/2gt^2$, where $u$ is vertical component of initial velocity and $g$ is gravitational acceleration. The maximum value of $y$ is reached at a time given by?

MY ANSWER

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=u-gt$$

To find maxima
$$u-gt=0$$
$$u=gt$$
$$t=\frac{u}{g}$$

Applying the values in original equation

$$y=\frac{u^2}{g}-\frac{u^2}{2g}$$
$$y=\frac{u^2}{2g}$$

The correct answer is $\frac{u}{g}$. What is the issue with my answer?

Comment: The problem is asking the **time** at which the maximum value of $y$ is reached. So you are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already realised the question is asking for the *time*, and that's been correctly calculated as $t= \frac ug$. However, you haven't actually shown that this time corresponds to a *maximum* height. For that you need the second derivative test. The second derivative $\frac {d^2y} {dt^2} = -g < 0$, which means that this value is indeed a maximum and not a minimum or an inflexion point. This is necessary for a complete solution.

Comment: Agreed, but it was an mcq, so I thought that could be neglected while solving.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that the question asked was to find the time. That way the correct answer is $\frac ug$ I won’t be deleting this question for anyone who may need it in the future.